# Getting solution of constraints when model gives infeasible solution

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, gurobi

I am coding an optimization problem. The model is giving infeasible solution. I want to check which constraint is giving infeasible solution. So far, I have checked online, but have not been able to come up with the solution to the problem. Can anyone help me? For example:in the code below, because of constraint 3 model is infeasible. How do I determine it from the solution? Thanks

```
from gurobipy import *

# Create a new model
m = Model("mip1")

# Create variables
x1 = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="x1")
x2 = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="x2")


# Integrate new variables
m.update()

# Set objective
m.setObjective(7*x1 + 2*x2, GRB.MAXIMIZE)


m.addConstr(-x1 + 2 * x2 <= 4, "constraint-0")


m.addConstr(5*x1 + x2 <= 20, "constraint-1")
m.addConstr(-2*x1 -2*x2 <= -7, "constraint-2")
m.addConstr(x1 <= -2, "constraint-3")
m.addConstr(x2 <= 4, "constraint-4")

m.optimize()

for v in m.getVars():
    print('%s %g' % (v.varName, v.x))

print('Obj: %g' % m.objVal)
```

Comment: Use [this](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/refman/cpp_grbmodel_computeiis.html).

Comment: @sudipta why x1 has to be less or equal than -2 ? Just out of curiosity

Answer (score 5):

an exemple :

```css
from gurobipy import *

# Create a new model
m = Model("mip1")
# Create variables
x1= m.addVar(lb=0,ub=62,vtype=GRB.INTEGER,name="x1")
x2 = m.addVar(lb=0,ub=50, vtype=GRB.INTEGER,name="x2")
m.update()

m.addConstr(-x1 + 2*x2 <= 4, "constraint-0")
m.addConstr(5*x1 + x2 <= 20, "constraint-1")
m.addConstr(-2*x1 -2*x2 <= -25, "constraint-2")
m.addConstr(x1 <= 2, "constraint-3")
#m.addConstr(x2 <= 50, "constraint-4")

m.update()

# Set objective
m.setObjective(7*x1 + 2*x2, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
m.update()

m.optimize()

status = m.status
if status == GRB.Status.OPTIMAL:
    for v in m.getVars():
        print('%s %g' % (v.varName, v.x))
    print('Obj: %g' % m.objVal)
       
elif status == GRB.Status.INFEASIBLE:
    print('Optimization was stopped with status %d' % status)
    # do IIS
    m.computeIIS()
    for c in m.getConstrs():
        if c.IISConstr:
            print('%s' % c.constrName)
```